# Tkinter Image viewer

Tags: python, image, tkinter, viewer

I'm trying to create a program using Tkinter that displays a thumbnail from several different directories in on window. So far I have this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Image, os

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Shot Viewer')
w, h, x, y = 1000, 1000, 0, 0
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))

#quit
def quit(root):
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

path = "/media/Expansion Drive/Heros Mission 3/Scenes/Scene 1-3/Shots/"
labels = []
for files in os.listdir(path):
    number = files.split("_")[1]
    filed = "/media/Expansion Drive/Heros Mission 3/Scenes/Scene 1-3/Shots/Shot_{} /Frames/Shot_{}_000000.png".format(number, number)
    if os.path.lexists(filed) == 'False':
        pass
    else:
        im = Image.open(imageFile)
        im.thumbnail((96, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        label = tk.Label(root, image=image, name=number)
        labels.append(label)

print labels

for label in labels:
    panel = label.grid()

panel2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button2 = tk.Button(panel2, text='Quit', command=lambda root=root:quit(root))
button2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='NW')

root.mainloop()
```

However this is not working, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: what do the errors say?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace, or the specific reason that you believe the code is not working

Comment: We cannot help without knowing what the error is. We are not mindreaders

Comment: Sorry, the error message is as follows:                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/Desktop/Shot_viewer_SO.py", line 34, in <module>
    panel2.grid(row=2, column=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1904, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
TclError: can't invoke "grid" command:  application has been destroyed

Comment: Also the tkinter main window appears but none of the images are in place (or the button)

Answer (score 1):

Use the glob module to help find the relevant files.

As for images failing to appear:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import glob

root = tk.Tk()

labels = []

for jpeg in glob.glob("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/*.jpg")[:5]:
    im = Image.open(jpeg)
    im.thumbnail((96, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
    label.pack()    
    label.img = photo # *
    # * Each time thru the loop, the name 'photo' has a different
    # photoimage assigned to it.
    # This means that you need to create a separate, 'longer-lived'
    # reference to each photoimage in order to prevent it from
    # being garbage collected.
    # Note that simply passing a photoimage to a Tkinter widget
    # is not enough to keep that photoimage alive.    
    labels.append(label)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are handling it correctly where you say `panels = label.grid()`. Instead, try to just do `label.grid` so it is not an assignment operator but an action.

Comment: Removing the brackets from label.grid does stop the error message. However the images still fail to appear in the window. Also I had to remove the button code as that was throwing this error: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2047, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1977, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: can't invoke "button" command:  application has been destroyed  (I couldn't put the full error as there weren't enough characters).